# Is there a way to auto-deploy from a git repo to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

For a while I've been serving a website off of Google's cloud storage. Since I don't modify it very much, it has always been a pain every time I need to change some code or fix some typo. My normal workflow is the following:

Edit code on local machine->push to github->copy code from local machine to GCS using gsutils

I recently came across this:
https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/cloud-repositories#push_to_a_web-hosted_repository

It looks like google cloud apps can now be auto-deployed from github. However, the example is for app engine, not cloud storage. Is there a way to auto-deploy to GCS?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a "Git to GCS" Github Action I made for that few days ago: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/git-to-gcs

The steps described in README are specifically for heaving a public bucket but it's unnecessary. And the repo does not have to be public at all -- I made mine public just to allow looking at my workflow file. Maybe I'll move it to README later.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting up jenkins for the same which keeps polling github for changes and you can setup set of tasks to be performed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "direct deploy" from git to GCS... then no, I don't see how you can. the Git-Appengine link is a feature in itself, one that is not extended to GCS.

Using something like [Satyam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2408747/satyam-singh) mentions could work though.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Build will do what you want. Builds can be triggered by commits, tag commits, etc. and you can push the code to Cloud Storage.